# Firefox ::after pseudo element not working

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a CSS class which outputs a line after a title

[image]

This works in Safari and Chrome but in Firefox the line is not appearing.

My Code:

```
.sidebar h2 {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar h2 span {
    background-color: #40d1b0;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
.sidebar h2::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.22em;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    z-index: -1;
}

<h2><span>Show</span></h2>
```

The container div has a class of `Sidebar`

### EDIT

JSFiddle as requested

http://jsfiddle.net/jerswell/Lxsmt96k/

Comment: Works fine after I removed `.sidebar` from all selectors.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: agreed.

Comment: It works fine here, using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur9b67q5/

Comment: Isolated code works fine. It's maybe by another cause. Maybe covered by other elements because of its `z-index: -1`

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks for this, I need to target just the H2 within this element though

Comment: @JustinErswell - Please reproduce the issue on a Stack Snippet or a Fiddle.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py added the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `z-index`, put a lower `z-index` to the sidebar class, so it won't be hidden anymore.

Here is a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsmt96k/2/), I have just simply put `z-index: -2;` to the `.sidebar` selector.

**PS (nitpicking):** In CSS3 `after` is not a pseudo-class but a pseudo-element, and there is a new notation for it: `::after` (however the old notation still works)

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the info, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we change z-index of .sidebar in minus value, later it can have a problem for layout. Other elements can overlap this element. We should use :

```
.sidebar h2{position:relative;}
.sidebar h2 span{position:relative;z-index:2;}
.sidebar h2:after{z-index:1;}
```